# Javascript function applied to single div

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to debug this code... I am trying to limit the function to just one div with the id "left". So far I have tried several variations of $('#left')
$("#left") to $(document.getElementById('left')) all with and without the hashmark.

It is affecting every table in the document rather than the single container.

Here is a link to the jfiddle...  [jfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/056ox06u/)

```
$('#left').ready(function() {

    promise = $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        dataType:"text",
        url:"sgi.csv",
        cache:false
    });

    promise.done(function(data){

        var dataArr = data.split("\n");

        $.each(dataArr,function(){
            if (this != "") {

                var row = new String("");
                valArr = this.split(",");
                    row += "<tr>"

                $.each(valArr, function(){
                    row += "<td>" + this +"</td>"
                });     

                    row += "</tr>"

                 $('tbody').append(row);

            }

        });

    });

    // Run script if request fails
    promise.fail(function() {
       console.log('A failure ocurred');
    });

});
```

Comment: Hi @Kevmoe, May I know what you want to achieve exactly. If you explain bit more, it will be helpful to solve your problem.

Comment: There's no difference between `$('#left').ready()` and `$(document).ready()`. The `.ready()` method ignores the element that it's called on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem code is `$('tbody').append(row);`. You are telling jQuery to append `row` to all `tbody` elements it finds.

If you only want to include it in `<tbody>` elements *that are children of* `#left` you need to do

```
$('#left tbody').append(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are calling `$('tbody').append(row);` you are appending to all `tbody` in the document. Just replace it with:

```
$('#left tbody').append(row);
```

Answer (score -1):

`$('#left tbody').append(row);` would solve your problem.